# Check if a number is in a range of a list

Tags: python

I have a problem that i don't know how to solve
Basically i have a list of names like this:

```
names = ['Andrea','21','Sophie',16]
```

and a list of numbers that are not always the same like this one:

```
details = ['21.43222','100.2334'] ##first time you run the program
details = ['23.53422','103.2334'] ##second time you run the program
```

What i would like is even if the result of the second time is different from the first one, it will link to the same person.

What i mean is that even if in my definitive list Andrea is linked to number 21.43222, even if we run  the program a second time and the result is in a range of +-5 (in this case between 16.43222 and 26.43222) the number will also linked to Andrea.
Thanks

Comment: `['Andrea','21','Sophie',16]` - interesting list of names.

Comment: how many details do you track? you could simply compare each of them, see which is the closest one.

Comment: You should probably use a dictionary for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, use a data structure that is more coherent to hold information:

```
names = ['Andrea','21','Sophie',16]
people = zip(names[::2], names[1::2])
# people is now: [('Andrea', '21'), ('Sophie', 16)]
```

Now, If you're trying to link each detail to the closest person:

```
# now test which who is closest to the detail (if that's what you meant to do)
map(lambda detail: (detail, min(people, key=lambda x: abs(float(x[1]) - float(detail)))), details)
# explanation: returns a tuple: (detail, person with minimal distance from detail)
```